# Overdetermined 3D Dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, spherical-coordinates

I've derived a system of ODE's, but there is a problem. Basically I have a set of three coupled ODE's $\lbrace\dot{\rho},\dot{\phi}_1,\dot{\phi}_2 \rbrace$ Now $\rho$ is in [0,1], but the two others are both in [0,2$\pi$]. Can I still consider them as spherical coordinates in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Isn't the system overdetermined? And what can I do about it.

Thanks

Comment: Are these ODEs periodic w.r.t. $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$?

Comment: How do you mean periodic? They both appear in sine functions, so I guess yes

Comment: I mean that if you write equations $\dot{\rho} = R(\rho, \phi_1, \phi_2), \; \dot{\phi_1} = \Phi_1(\rho, \phi_1, \phi_2), \; \dot{\phi_2} = \Phi_2(\rho, \phi_1, \phi_2)$ then $R, \Phi_1, \Phi_2$ are periodic functions of $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$.

Comment: Yes that's true

Comment: I think that you need to check whether the equations treat the points that are same from point of view of spherical coordinates as same in your system. At least we already know that your system treats $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ as angles.

Comment: Okay thank you for your reply